# Split up column based on range of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find the indexes where a new range of 100 values begins.

In the case below, since the first row is 0, the next index would be the next number above 100 (7).
At index 7, the value is 104, so the next index would be next number above 204 (15).
At index 15, the value is 205, so the next index would be the next number above 305 (n/a).

Therefore the output would be [0, 7, 15].

```
0           0
1           0
2           4
3           10
4           30
5           65
6           92
7           104
8           108
9           109
10          123
11          132
12          153
13          160
14          190
15          205
16          207
17          210
18          240
19          254
20          254
21          254
22          263
23          273
24          280
25          293
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorted data, we can use `searchsorted` -

```
In [98]: df.head()
Out[98]: 
    A
0   0
1   0
2   4
3  10
4  30

In [143]: df.A.searchsorted(np.arange(0,df.A.iloc[-1],100))
Out[143]: array([ 0,  7, 15])
```

If you need based on dataframe/series index, index it by `df.index` -

```
In [101]: df.index[_]
Out[101]: Int64Index([0, 7, 15], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: What if my column happens to have floats? Seems I get a `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 3):

You can do [`zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to create three digit numbers:

```
# convert number to string
df['grp'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.zfill(3).str[0]
print(df)

     a    b grp
0    0    0   0
1    1    0   0
2    2    4   0
3    3   10   0
4    4   30   0
5    5   65   0
6    6   92   0
7    7  104   1
8    8  108   1
9    9  109   1
10  10  123   1
11  11  132   1
12  12  153   1
13  13  160   1
14  14  190   1
15  15  205   2

# get first row from each group
ix = df.groupby('grp').first()['a'].to_numpy()
print(ix)    

array([ 0,  7, 15])
```